# How do I get a specific value from a feeder using a number?

Tags: scala, gatling

So assume that I have a feeder with list of values, for example:

```
[{
  "id": "000000066",
  "id": "000000004",
  "id": "000000002",
   etc...
}]
```

Now, I'd like to send value number 3 (000000002) to a function that saves something in the session, for example:

```
exec(session => {session.set("value",valueGenerator(session("feederList(3)").as[String]))})
```

(feederList is my feeder session variable)
Obviously the above doesn't work - Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you insist in using Gatling built-ins feeders to read data and use them as CSV readers, you can user [`readRecords`](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/#grabbing-records) to grab the full Array in memory. You can then user the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/) to grab the record you want, in functions or an in [exec](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#exec) block.